# How to get spring MVC to completely ignore the Accept Header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, header, annotations

I have a pretty standard Spring MVC configuration using  and .

I have a login page wired up to login.html using the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(HttpSession session)
```

The problem I am having is that unless the user agent requesting the page sends an Accept header of "text/html" they are getting back a 404.  We have some clients with a browser configuration that is sending */* and they can't get to our site.

Furthermore, the HTTP spec states that if the Accept header is not presented, then it should be assumed that the user agent accepts */*

So my question is, how do I get Spring MVC to not check the Accept header at all when matching the request to my handler?  I would like the mapping to work regardless of what Accept value they send and even if the Accept value is left off completely.

Comment: The problem is in your servlet config, or perhaps a filter defined in web.xml. Offhand, I can't tell you what you've done, just that it isn't caused by the @RequestMapping. If you post those two documents, I'm sure someone will tell you what to delete/edit.

Comment: Actually, I'll amend my comment: it isn't caused by *that* @RequestMapping. Look for a class-level @RequestMapping that includes a `consumes` argument. If you don't find one, I'm back to the web.xml or servlet config.

Comment: Or possibly you may have a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` defined somewhere in your servlet context..

Comment: As it turned out I had an Interceptor I didn't realize was modifying the viewName based on the Accept header and thus the 404 was legit in that the view couldn't be found.  Removing that faulty logic fixed it.

Comment: @D-Rock - given that this question is unlikely to help anyone in the future, and doesn't have any answers, might I suggest that you delete it?

Comment: I don't see a reason to delete this Q. I think its quite likely someone will have a similar issue and although the chances of them having the same "cause" is very unlikely, the comments here provide a logical set of steps to check for things, that could be very helpful (especially for less experienced coders).

Comment: @nickdos - personally, I think that having the same cause is extremely likely. Unfortunately, the OP has written a lot of invalid assumptions that will get indexed by Google, and doesn't provide *any* information that is relevant to the cause. Which IMO makes the Internet a worse place, whether or not the comments that I and *Teja Kantamneni* provided might be helpful.